# Get all nodes in a DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, dom

How do I get all nodes in a DOMDocument without using XPath? I'm not looking for `getElementsByTagName('*')`, which only gets element nodes.

Comment: See if you can use `$('*')` using jquery!

Comment: could you explain why to get ALL nodes?

Comment: Do you need except leaf nodes?

Comment: I was planning on getting all nodes and discarding everything that isn't an element node, text node, or comment node. If it's possible to get only those nodes, then that'll be even better.